# Applying different styles to different elements in a better way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this function , which applies css styles + couple of plugins + hide/show to a bunch of elements.
These elements are children of "item" element and have id's which contain this "item" number. Also these rules apply for different types of items.
It works fine, but it is monstrous. Can you suggest couple of better ways of doing this?

**Note:**  *PackageElement* and *duration* are global vars.

```
function HideItemElements(Type,ItemNum) {
                    switch (Type) {
                        case 'HW':
                            $("#Country" + ItemNum).addClass("Chzn").show().chosenImage({ width: "204px", no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"});                         
                            $("#Countrylabel" + ItemNum).show();
                            $("#LineOptions" + ItemNum).text("Edit Support");
                            $("#ItemImage" + ItemNum).attr("src", "Styles/images/u79_normal.png");
                            break;
                        case 'SW':
                            if (PackageElement.attr("name") == "HW") {
                            }
                            else {
                                $("#Serials" + ItemNum).show();
                                $("#Serialslabel" + ItemNum).show();
                                $("#OtherOpts" + ItemNum)
                                .attr("style", "height:113px");
                            }
                            $("#ItemImage" + ItemNum).attr("src", "Styles/images/u131_normal.png");
                            break;
                        case 'SERVICE':
                            $("#ItemImage" + ItemNum).attr("src", "Styles/images/u149_normal.png");
                            $("#LineOptions" + ItemNum).hide();
                            break;
                        case 'CONTRACT':
                            if (PackageElement.attr("name") == "HW") {
                                $("#Countrylabel" + ItemNum).hide();
                                $("#Country" + ItemNum).hide().removeClass("Chzn");
                                $("#OtherOpts" + ItemNum).children().eq(2).hide();
                                if (duration.get_selectedItem().get_value() == "Other") {
                                    $("#ItemStarting" + ItemNum).show()
                                    .datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" })
                                    .datepicker("setDate", "+0d")
                                    .attr("style", "top:9px");
                                    $("#ItemStartinglabel" + ItemNum).show()
                                    .attr("style", "top:-4px");
                                    $("#ItemEnd" + ItemNum).show()
                                    .datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" })
                                    .datepicker("setDate", "+1y")
                                    .attr("style", "top:52px");
                                    $("#ItemEndlabel" + ItemNum).show()
                                    .attr("style", "top:38px");
                                    $("#OtherOpts" + ItemNum)
                                    .attr("style", "height:82px");
                                }
                                else {
                                    $("#ItemDuration" + ItemNum).show().addClass("Chzn").chosen({ width: "204px", disable_search: true });
                                    $("#ItemDurationlabel" + ItemNum).show();
                                }
                            }
                            else if (PackageElement.attr("name") == "SW") {
                                $("#Serials" + ItemNum).hide();
                                $("#Serialslabel" + ItemNum).hide();
                                if (duration.get_selectedItem().get_value() == "Other") {
                                    $("#ItemStarting" + ItemNum).show()
                                     .datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" })
                                     .datepicker("setDate", "+0d")
                                     .attr("style", "top:9px");
                                    $("#ItemStartinglabel" + ItemNum).show()
                                    .attr("style", "top:-4px");
                                    $("#ItemEnd" + ItemNum).show()
                                    .datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" })
                                    .datepicker("setDate", "+1y")
                                    .attr("style", "top:52px");
                                    $("#ItemEndlabel" + ItemNum).show()
                                    .attr("style", "top:38px");
                                    $("#OtherOpts" + ItemNum)
                                    .attr("style", "height:82px");
                                }
                                else {
                                    $("#ItemDuration" + ItemNum).show()
                                    .attr("style", "top:9px").addClass("Chzn").chosen({ width: "204px", disable_search: true });
                                    $("#ItemDurationlabel" + ItemNum).show();
                                    $("#ItemStartinglabel" + ItemNum).show()
                                    .attr("style", "top:38px");
                                    $("#ItemStarting" + ItemNum).show()
                                    .datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" })
                                    .datepicker("setDate", "+0d")
                                    .attr("style", "top:52px");
                                    $("#OtherOpts" + ItemNum)
                                    .attr("style", "height:82px");
                                } 
                            }
                            else {              
                                if (duration.get_selectedItem().get_value() == "Other") {
                                    $("#ItemStarting" + ItemNum).show()
                                     .datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" })
                                     .datepicker("setDate", "+0d")
                                     .attr("style", "top:9px");
                                    $("#ItemStartinglabel" + ItemNum).show()
                                    .attr("style", "top:-4px");
                                    $("#ItemEnd" + ItemNum).show()
                                    .datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" })
                                    .datepicker("setDate", "+1y")
                                    .attr("style", "top:52px");
                                    $("#ItemEndlabel" + ItemNum).show()
                                    .attr("style", "top:38px");
                                    $("#OtherOpts" + ItemNum)
                                    .attr("style", "height:208px");
                                }
                                else {
                                    $("#ItemDuration" + ItemNum).show()
                                    .attr("style", "top:9px").addClass("Chzn").chosen({ width: "204px", disable_search: true });
                                    $("#ItemDurationlabel" + ItemNum).show();
                                    $("#ItemStartinglabel" + ItemNum).show()
                                    .attr("style", "top:38px");
                                    $("#ItemStarting" + ItemNum).show()
                                    .datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" })
                                    .datepicker("setDate", "+0d")
                                    .attr("style", "top:52px");
                                    $("#OtherOpts" + ItemNum)
                                    .attr("style", "height:208px");
                                }
                                $("#Serials" + ItemNum).show()
                                .attr("style", "top:96px; left: -97px; width: 296px;");
                                $("#Serialslabel" + ItemNum).show()
                                .attr("style", "left:-97px; top:84px");
                            }
                            $("#LineOptions" + ItemNum).hide();
                            $("#ItemImage" + ItemNum).attr("src", "Styles/images/u77_normal.png");
                            break;
                        case 'ACCESSORY':
                            $("#LineOptions" + ItemNum).hide();
                            $("#ItemImage" + ItemNum).attr("src", "Styles/images/u90_normal.png");
                            break;
                    }
```

If you need me to add something to the question - ask for it in the comments please.

**Edit:** The main issue is the "contract" case.

Comment: Note - I already see an unnecessary if{}else{} in SW case

Comment: try to refactoring it yourself and if stuck somewhere, ask a more relevant question

Comment: @ A. Wolff This is the best I could achieve. The SW case is just a blured eye issue( haven't noticed on first sight)

Comment: Instead of the `attr` method like `.attr("style", "top: 52px")` you can just use the `css` method like `.css("top", "52px")` it will look way better

Comment: From a glance, you're doing the same thing in alot of the different cases, the one that caught my eye was setting the date format to `dd-mm-yy`. If the date format is always going to be `dd-mm-yy`, do you really need to state so in every occurrence?

Comment: I would suggest using more css and less jquery. You can show/hide elements according to a parent css class.

Comment: Thank you @MLeFevre. I've used this hint too. 
I changed this to `$(".hasDatepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy");` 
in the end of a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also tidy things up significantly if you had separate functions to handle each process, for example:

```
$("#ItemStarting" + ItemNum).show()
  .datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" })
  .datepicker("setDate", "+0d")
  .attr("style", "top:52px");
```

is something that appears 5 times in your switch, you could create a function & handle it like this instead

```
function setup_item_starting(ItemNum, date_format, set_date, top_px) {
    $("#ItemStarting" + ItemNum).show()
      .datepicker({ dateFormat: date_format })
      .datepicker("setDate", set_date)
      .css("top", top_px);
}
```

and then simply perform calls like:

```
setup_item_starting(ItemNum, "dd-mm-yy", "+0d", "52px");
```

in your switch statement, whenever you need to perform a change.

Do the same kind of thing for your other elements like `ItemDurationlabel` `ItemDuration` `ItemEnd` etc.. and you'll quickly chop your switch statement down to a reasonable size.

Comment: I'll Select this answer because it fits my current needs the most.

Comment: @MaksymStepanenko You never can think of what you need when you're actually doing it! For example, this solution could be improved even further by just passing the element you want to alter to a function, rather having individual functions for every element. Why didn't I just write that at the time?!

Comment: @ MLeFevre you're right, but I'm not writing the function right now. The project is ready, I'm just cleaning the code before production.
But anyway - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to change the DOM/HTML presentation based on runtime state in javascript. It looks like you're looking for a binding framework such as KnockoutJs or AngularJs!

A binding framework does exactly what you need: it moves the behavior into declarations (see example) so that you then only have to manipulate your javascript runtime state afterwards. Doing so, frees up your hands to deal with your businesslogic without having to deal with event-handlers and DOM manipulation all the time. The binding framework will reflect any runtime state change in the DOM for you.

This is also the 'modern' way to go these days, especially in larger (enterprise?) projects. Especially AngularJs is currently soaring in popularity due to its robustness (provides a total solution, including dependency injection, routing, service management and so on).

### Declarative behavior example with KnockoutJs:

**Javascript runtime state:**

```
var countries = [{ name: 'Germany', type: 'HW' }, { name: 'Iran', type: 'SW' }];
```

**HTML with behavior binding**

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: countries">
    <li data-bind="text: $data.name, css: { Chzn: $data.type == 'HW' }"></li>
</ul>
```

Now any change to this data will automagically result in changes to the HTML. AngularJs will have similar facilities.

- http://learn.knockoutjs.com
- http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

Comment: Thank you for this answer @Plantface. I'll use it in my future projects. Right now I would prefer just to tidy up because it works fine, just looks bad.